# Display a three.js scene after clicking on an image illustrating this scene

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

I would like to display, after clicking on an image illustrating a Three.js scene, this Three.js scene and be able to run it. Once one has clicked on image, I would like to include Three.js scene into a frame with a grey background (like [`lightbox`](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) does with images)

Here's below an example of what I would like to get :

[image: Three.js scene into frame]

You can see this WebGL scene on the following link :

[Three.js scene](http://beulu.com/test_width_dat_gui_animation/index.html)

As you can see, this scene fills the entire window of browser.

If someone could give me some clues to acheive this, it would be nice.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Include your image with classic html.
2. Include an empty div with a known id with classic html.
3. Add an event listener to execute a function (eg. init()) when somebody clicks the image.
4. This init function should init the THREE.WebGLRenderer, the THREE.Scene, render() etc.
5. The function should then add the element in the empty div with : `document.getElementById("empty-div").appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);`
6. To make it seem like a frame, you should then toggle CSS class. Do you know how to make such a frame in CSS ?
7. Eventually, to update the size of the Three Scene when the user resizes the window, you can add `window.addEventListener('resize', resizeFunction, false);` and the resizeFunction should use `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` to execute `renderer.setSize(width, height);`